# Form is been redirected to the correct 2nd page but i don't receive the info in emails where is sent to

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a html form named **formulario.html** that when he is submitted and with success it's redirected to a Second page named **agradecimentos.html**.
Everything is going well but i don't receive the info from the form in the 2 emails that he's been sent to.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Here is a part of the **formulario.html** code:

```
<form action="suporte_email.php" method="post" name="formulario" id="formulario" >

<!-- THAT'S TOO MUCH CODE BUT I CHECKED THAT AND IT SEEMS NOT TO BE WRONG -->

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

The **agradecimentos.html** is a simple html code where i redirect clients to a page from the site.

My .php code is named **suporte_email.php** like you can see where is action. My problem is that i don't receive the info from the form and i still don't get where is my mistake.

**suporte_email.php**

```
<?php
$crlf = "\r\n";
//Get Data
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];                    
    $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];              
    $contacto = $_POST['contacto'];            
    $email = $_POST['email'];                  
    $marca = $_POST['marca'];                   
    $other = $_POST['other'];                    
    $serial_number = $_POST['serial_number'];     
    $garantia = $_POST['garantia'];               
    $contrato = $_POST['contrato'];             
    $permissoes = $_POST['permissoes'];           
    $descricao_avaria = $_POST['descricao_avaria'];
    $checkbox = $_POST["checkbox"];
    $radio = $_POST["radio"];

 // Parse/Format/Verify Data
       $to      = "teste@teste.pt, $email"; 
       $from    = "Suporte";
       $subject = "Formulário de Suporte";

       $email_body = "$crlf De: $nome$crlf Email: $email$crlf Assunto: $subject$crlf$crlf Empresa: $empresa$crlf Contacto: $contacto$crlf Marca: $marca$crlf Outra: $other$crlf Número de Série: $serial_number$crlf Garantia: $radio$crlf Contrato: $checkbox$crlf Tipo de Suporte: $permissoes$crlf$crlf Descrição da Avaria: $descricao_avaria";

       // Setup EMAIL headers, particularly to support UTF-8
       // We set the EMAIL headers here, these will be sent out with your message
       // for the receiving email client to use.
       $headers ='From: '.$to . $crlf . 
                  'Reply-To: ' .$to  . $crlf . 
                  'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' .  $crlf .
                  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();



       // Then we pass the headers into our mail function
       mail($to, $from, $subject, $email_body, $headers);
       header('Location: agradecimentos.html');
?>
```

//Garantia is a radio button and Contrato is a Checkbox.

Comment: Do you have a mail server on your system? `mail()` returns a status, its not much use to be honest but it would be a good idea to look at it and maybe output an error if it returns false

Comment: Also, you are doing ZERO error checking on your mail sending.

Comment: Yes i have a mail server @RiggsFolly  ok.. but it still will happen the same, the info would not be sent

Comment: Hum.. what you suggest to make it work @Epodax ? :)

Comment: and a simple call to mail works? viz: `mail('teste@teste.pt', 'My Subject', 'testing 1-2-3');`

Comment: Yes @RamRaider and that is what i think is strange.. Is been sent but don't receive info in email

Answer (score 1):

your

```
 mail($to, $from, $subject, $email_body, $headers);
```

should be

```
 mail($to, $subject, $email_body, $headers);
```

> `mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters);`
>   [PHP mail() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)

adding `From` and `Cc` option should be

```
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
           "CC: somebodyelse@example.com";
```

Adding `html` version should be like this

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

**EDIT 01**

```
        $email_body = "De: $nome
        \r\n Email: $email
        \r\n Assunto: $subject
        \r\n Empresa: $empresa
        \r\n Contacto: $contacto
        \r\n Marca: $marca
        \r\n Outra: $other
        \r\n Número de Série: $serial_number
        \r\n Garantia: $radio
        \r\n Contrato: $checkbox
        \r\n Tipo de Suporte: $permissoes
        \r\n Descrição da Avaria: $descricao_avaria";
```

Comment: i tried that but still don't receive info in my email

Comment: info means `$email_body` content ??

Comment: and what is in `$crlf` ??

Comment: Sorry, the info is all the information that i put in my form. All the information in the form should be received in a email with was coded with php and it is is the $email_body  @Abdulla.     The $crlf = "\n";

Comment: Thank you @Abdulla changed that but still i don't receive the $email_body in my email when sent

Comment: remove your headers and use this `$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";`

Comment: *I have done that but i think that part isn't the problem :\